# Copy HTML data to another element using data-attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I'm currently working on building a webshop. Each product on the homepage is rendered automatically in a box using a "for" loop. I created a preview button on each product-box so visitors aren't send of the homepage when they want detailed information about a product. By clicking the preview button a popup should come up with the product name (and more information).

Basically I want the dynamic text {{product.title}} be reproduced in the popup box of the corresponding product.

What's the best way to manage this? Is this by using data-attributes?

```
<!-- PRODUCT SECTION -->
<section id="Portfolio" class="clearfix portfolio {{ theme.product_display }}"> 
  {% for product %}
  <article class="portfolio-product">
    <figure class="portfolio-productimage">
      <a href="{{ product.url | url }}">
        <img src="{{ product.image | url_image(product.title) }}" class="img-responsive" alt="{{ product.title }}">
        <span role="button" data-popup="#quick_view_product" class="button_type_5 box_s_none color_light r_corners tr_all_hover d_xs_none">Quick View</span>
      </a>
    </figure>
    <div class="portfolio-producttitle">
      <h3>{{ product.title }}</h3>
    </div>
  </article>
  {% endfor %}
</section>
<!-- END PRODUCT SECTION -->

<!-- PRODUCT POPUP -->
<div class="popup_wrap d_none" id="quick_view_product">
  <section class="popup r_corners shadow">
    <button class="bg_tr color_dark tr_all_hover text_cs_hover close f_size_large"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
    <div class="clearfix">
      <div class="full_column">
        <h2 class="m_bottom_10">{{ product.title }}</h2> // THIS IS WHERE THE AUTOMATED PRODUCT TITLE SHOULD BE DISPLAYED            
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
<!-- END PRODUCT POPUP -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place the popup markup in the for loop and use the variables from the for or you can use data-atributes as you sugested to pass data from the looped markup to the popup .

The avantage of data-atributes over placing the popup markup in the loop is less markup on the page ->small html page -> fast render time

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. However, if I place the popup markup in the for loop as you suggest. The popup only seems to render the product name of the first product in the loop. On top of that, there's the faster render time as you mentioned by using data-attributes.

Comment: the popup in the for loop needs a unique data-popup atribute for exemple your product id  `data-popup="#quick_view_product_{{product.id}}"`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Madalin! You made my day. I've been looking 2 days for an answer.

Here the working mark-up:

```
<!-- PRODUCT SECTION -->
<section id="Portfolio" class="clearfix portfolio {{ theme.product_display }}"> 
  {% for product %}
  <article class="portfolio-product">
    <figure class="portfolio-productimage">
      <a href="{{ product.url | url }}">
        <img src="{{ product.image | url_image(product.title) }}" class="img-responsive" alt="{{ product.title }}">
        <span role="button" data-popup="#quick_view_product_{{ product.id }}" class="button_type_5 box_s_none color_light r_corners tr_all_hover d_xs_none">Quick View</span>
      </a>
    </figure>
    <div class="portfolio-producttitle">
      <h3>{{ product.title }}</h3>
    </div>
  </article>
  {% endfor %}
</section>
<!-- END PRODUCT SECTION -->

<!-- PRODUCT POPUP -->
<div class="popup_wrap d_none" id="quick_view_product_{{ product.id }}">
  <section class="popup r_corners shadow">
    <button class="bg_tr color_dark tr_all_hover text_cs_hover close f_size_large"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
    <div class="clearfix">
      <div class="full_column">
        <h2 class="m_bottom_10">{{ product.title }}</h2> // THIS IS WHERE THE AUTOMATED PRODUCT TITLE SHOULD BE DISPLAYED            
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
<!-- END PRODUCT POPUP -->
```